# How to derive this equation?

Tags: calculus

I have problem to understand calculus problem.

for some $t \in (0,1)$

if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable and $p$ is directional vector

$$\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x)+ \int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+tp)p \, dt$$

How to derive this equation?

Maybe it's from taylor expansion.

But, I don't know how to derive this equation based on taylor expansion.

Comment: What is the derivative of $t \mapsto \nabla f(x+tp)$? Then apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: hm... is  the derivative of ∇f(x+tp)  = ∇∇f(x+tp)p?? why integral is used in this equation?

Comment: As with the single dimension, we have $\phi(x+p) = \phi(x)+\int_0^1 \phi'(x+tp)p dt$.